# Gaussian Low-pass Filter in Android OpenCV.

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opencv, image-recognition

In order to make an image with better quality, I had do lots of research on filters. Filters are categorized into low, medium and high. After an analysis of these categories of filters, I conclude that Gaussian low-pass filter is the most suitable for me. And I had researched on how to code it in Android.

Finally I found that OpenCV has this function. After a few days of headache, I still can't find any solution since I am new to OpenCV. Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html#smoothing

More specifically:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur

And for Android it is something like this:

Do not forget to import Imgproc.

```
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
// (...)    
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(Mat src, Mat dst, Size ksize, double sigmaX, double sigmaY=0, int borderType=Imgproc.BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

Comment: Is there a tutorial about these stuff, but in Java?